# How to markup price in Magento2

Tags: magento2, php, price, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I want to markup prices but Magento2 provides only a discounted option (I don't know how it is possible!). I'm trying to modify the expression in `Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\ ProductPriceCalculator`

> **From**
>
> case 'by_percent':
> $productPrice = $productPrice * (1 - $ruleData['action_amount'] / 100);
>
> **To**
>
> case 'by_percent':
> $productPrice = $productPrice * (1 + $ruleData['action_amount'] / 100);

It should work because the math formula is correct but when I apply the rule in the frontend it shows only the regular price. I suppose there is something other that limits the price to be not over the regular price but I'm not able to find and manage it.

The full code is as below:

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer;

/**
 * Product price calculation according to rules settings.
 */
class ProductPriceCalculator
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    private $priceCurrency;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency)
    {
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates product price.
     *
     * @param array $ruleData
     * @param null $productData
     * @return float
     */
    public function calculate($ruleData, $productData = null)
    {
        if ($productData !== null && isset($productData['rule_price'])) {
            $productPrice = $productData['rule_price'];
        } else {
            $productPrice = $ruleData['default_price'];
        }

        switch ($ruleData['action_operator']) {
            case 'to_fixed':
                $productPrice = min($ruleData['action_amount'], $productPrice);
                break;
            case 'to_percent':
                $productPrice = $productPrice * $ruleData['action_amount'] / 100;
                break;
            case 'by_fixed':
                $productPrice = max(0, $productPrice - $ruleData['action_amount']);
                break;
            case 'by_percent':
                $productPrice = $productPrice * (1 + $ruleData['action_amount'] / 100);
                break;
            default:
                $productPrice = 0;
        }

        return $this->priceCurrency->round($productPrice);
    }
}
```